# My wrong answer was accepted. Can it be fixed?

Tags: discussion

I supplied an answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8740/identify-this-long-leaved-plant-having-big-orange-flowers) which I now believe is incorrect in the identification but correct in how to culture. Another user has the correct identification.

I could delete my own answer which also deletes my notes on how to culture it or I could change my existing answer.  The latter does not seem right as user BRM should get the credit.

Are there existing editing tools to correct this? A merge or ....

Sigh: Did it again, [another wrong answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/is-it-safe-to-eat-dandelions-previously-treated-with-a-selective-iron-herbicide) to a confusingly worded question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to leave a comment asking the OP to accept the other answer. At that point, you can edit the information about the plant's care into that answer, and delete your own if you choose. You won't be able to delete your answer while it has the accept mark.

However, moderators **can** delete accepted answers, so if you feel strongly enough about it, let us know (either by flagging the post or by replying here) and we can take care of it.